# PHP Standard author header comments

Tags: php, header, comments, standards

What is the format I should use for PHP header comments?

Is this the same for PEAR as found here http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.header.php?

What should be contained?

```
<?php

/**
 * database.php
 *
 * Database access
 *
 * @category   CategoryName
 * @package    PackageName
 * @author     Mike
 * @copyright  2013 Mike
 * @license    http://www.php.net/license/3_0.txt  PHP License 3.0
 * @version    CVS: $Id:$
 * @link       http://pear.php.net/package/PackageName
 * @see        NetOther, Net_Sample::Net_Sample()
 * @since      File available since Release 1.2.0
 * @deprecated File deprecated in Release 2.0.0
 */

?>
```

Could someone please explain what each of these actually mean other than the author and copyright.

Does entering the version number here do anything other than show the programmer? Can it be used by the system itself?

`@package` and `@category` What do these two do? And again, are they used by the system or is it purely for the programmer?

Comment: See [phpdoc](http://phpdoc.org/). It's used to compile documentation in a readable form and can also be parsed by most ide's.

Comment: Can I install this locally on my Mac and use it in conjunction with SUblimeText?

Comment: Probably but I'm not really familiar with sublime. I use vim ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the PHPDoc documentation. It contains explanations of all of the tags.

**phpDocumentor 3.0**
https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/index.html

Answer (score 5):

Check out the PHPDoc.org [@author](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/author.html#author) tag.

**Syntax**

```
@author [name] [<email address>]
```

**Examples**

```
 /**
  * @author My Name
  * @author My Name <my.name@example.com>
  */
```

Answer (score 1):

Since PEAR head was made for PHP4 code with small updates to work with PHP5 I'd look as something more in line with current standards. @package and @category were something that PEAR used to split up code before PHP had namespaces. All new code should not use them except if you are planning to use PEAR to distro your code. As someone else already give link for PhpDoc it's the best place to learn about the available tags. I'd also take a look at the tags other major projects that you find on GitHub and other sites use as most use similar but more updated styles with the most common tags.

Answer (score 0):

I used this comment style for function

```
/**
* @author     Azxster
* @datetime   04 March 2020
* @perpose    Standard commenting way
* @input      Get comment requirement
* @output     Show comment represent the way
*/
```

Comment: maybe spell @purpose correctly though =)